# Excel VBA Filter Criteria

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

I have two columns to filter. The first column filters just fine.

Its the second column I have the problem with.

When I uses the code  **Criteria2:="<>** it don't work. If I uses the code  **Criteria2:="=...** it works.

So the problem I have is with the "<>" or Not Equal To" statement.

```
With ActiveSheet 
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("$A$1:$BM$15806")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:="Participating", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Registered"
        .AutoFilter Field:=41, Criteria1:="<>INACTIVE STATUS~*~*~*~*~*~*~*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>HOLD -- Inactive Form in Process -- Not Recv'd"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Compile error? If not an compile error, what is your expected outcome and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: What I mean is after the macro runs and I go to that column nothing is selected in the advace filter drop down, meaning the filter did not work

Comment: Mike, you mentioned "advance filter drop down" but this code wouldn't affect the advanced filter.  Have you tried using the macro recorder?  With so many columns, xlAnds and xlOrs, long cell contents, asterisks, recording the actions might reveal a logic or typing error.  One other thing is with that many rows, depending on your Excel version, the filtering might not show in the Autofilter dropdown so be sure to check your results some other way too.

Answer (score 0):

Easily seen with Record Macro applied to a simple example, Excel's filtering is 'positive only' - not by exception. That is, filtering `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` to exclude say `e` is **not** achieved by specifying "give me everything but `e`", rather by specifying "give me `a`, `b`, `c`,`d`, `f`". In this context there is no "Not Equal To" statement.